# Realtime document permanantly unable to be loaded due to server error

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

Earlier today we started to see instances of server errors popping up on an old realtime document. This is a persistent error and the end result appears to be that the document is **completely inaccessible** using the gapi.drive.realtime.load endpoint. Not great.

However the same document is accessible through the gapi.client.drive.realtime.get endpoint. Which is great for data recovery, but not so great for actually using the document. It's possible I can 'fix' the document by doing a 'drive.realtime.update', but haven't tried as hopefully the doc can be used to track down the bug.

Document ID: 0B9I5WUIeAEJ1Y3NLQnpqQWVlX1U

App ID: 597847337936

500 Error Message: "Document was not successfully migrated to new UserKey format"

Anyone else seeing this issue? Can I provide any additional information?

Comment: From the error message that you got "Document was not successfully migrated to new UserKey format" It is safe to say that you need to update the file to get the new format like the message error. I checked the internet to find this error, but I got 0 results. I suggest you to proceed with your intention to update the file and check if the issue is gone. If it's not, then try to report a [bug](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/support) about this. This is the only [docu](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) that I found that has a `userKey` format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've already filed a bug on their bug tracker. The migration is internal on Google's end and not something we requested. The data in the particular file does not need to be recovered, the issue is that it may affect our users that do have critical data that does need to be recovered. Appreciate you taking the time to reply!